# accessing the the first element in each array in an ArrayList and averaging all of them

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

Beginner here. I tried to find any questions that may address this but I couldn't, so I apologize in advance if this ends up being a duplicate.

So I have a Double[] called pay containing three Double values (totalPay, basePay, hoursWorked) that I'm storing in an ArrayList called payList.

I am looking for a way to be able to determine the average totalPay, average basePay and average hoursWorked, 
I tried using foreach, but it doesn't seem to working.

```
         Double avgTotalPay=0.0;
         Double avgBasePay=0.0;
         Double avgHoursWworked=0.0;

         for(Double paym[] : payList){  
             for(Double p: paym){       
             avgTotalPay+=paym[0];
             }

            avgTotalPay=avgTotalPay/payList.size(); 
         }

         for(Double paym[] : payList){ 
             for(Double p: paym){       
             avgBasePay+=paym[1];
             }

            avgBasePay=avgBasePay/payList.size(); 
         }       


         for(Double paym[] : payList){ 
             for(Double p: paym){       
             avgHoursWworked+=paym[2];
             }

            avgHoursWworked=avgHoursWworked/payList.size(); 
         }  

         System.out.println("Average Total Pay is: "+avgTotalPay+"\n Average Base Pay is: "+avgBasePay
                 +"\n Average number of hours worked is: "+avgHoursWworked);
```

(When the user enters 0 for the base pay and the number of hours worked, the function should average the total pay, base pay and hours worked.)

Please enter a base pay:
 
10
Please enter the number of hours worked:
 
10
Total Pay is $100.0 and Hourly Pay is $10.0/hour
 

Please enter a base pay:
 
500
Please enter the number of hours worked:
 
50
Total Pay is $1000.0 and Hourly Pay is $20.0/hour (max total pay can't exceed
 $1000)
Please enter a base pay:
 
0
Please enter the number of hours worked:
 
0
Average Total Pay is: 2250.0
 Average Base Pay is: 1125.0
 Average number of hours worked is: 112.5

If I calculate the averages by hand, they should be 
$550 for total pay,
$250 for base pay, and
30 for number of hours worked

Comment: What output are you getting and what is your expected output?

Comment: Can you share the definition of `pay` `paym` `payList` ?

Comment: @RajeevRanjan ArrayList<Double[]> payList = new ArrayList<Double[]>();
   Double[] pay= new Double[3];

Comment: @user2023608 I added a sample execution of the code to the question. :)

Answer (score 1):

You do not need all of those loops, nor do you need to use the `Double` wrapper. One loop should be sufficient, no inner loops. Like,

```
double avgTotalPay = 0.0;
double avgBasePay = 0.0;
double avgHoursWworked = 0.0;
for (Double[] paym : payList) {
    avgTotalPay += paym[0];
    avgBasePay += paym[1];
    avgHoursWworked += paym[2];
}
avgTotalPay /= payList.size();
avgBasePay /= payList.size();
avgHoursWworked /= payList.size();
```

**or**, if you're using Java 8+, you could do it with `Stream`(s) like

```
double avgTotalPay = payList.stream().mapToDouble(x -> x[0]).average()
        .orElse(0);
double avgBasePay = payList.stream().mapToDouble(x -> x[1]).average()
        .orElse(0);
double avgHoursWworked = payList.stream().mapToDouble(x -> x[2]).average()
        .orElse(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Can be solved in an iteration

```
double avgTotalPay = 0.0;
double avgBasePay = 0.0:
double avgHrsWorked = 0.0;
for (Double pay[] : payList) {
     avgTotalPay += pay[0];
     avgBasePay += pay[1];
     avgHrsWorked += pay[2];
 }
 avgTotalPay /= payList.size();
 avgBasePay /= payList.size();
 avgHrsWorked /= payList.size();
```